# Entity Framework - how to query for a set of elements AFTER a specific element

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Most likely this is a simple question, but I'm very new to Entity Framework.  Basically, what I need to do is to get the next n elements after a specific id.  A rest query comes in like so:

```
GET /thing?amount=1000&after=3b54ec58-f1ca-41e7-9941-fbf5d945f197
```

There is a list of things with guids for ids.  Given this query, I need to get the next 1000 elements after id 3b54ec58-f1ca-41e7-9941-fbf5d945f197.

Getting the first 1000 is easy enough,

```
_context.Things.Take(limit).ToList();
```

I assume I could skip x elements until id=after, but just not sure how to set it all up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This basically is the same as [Get rows that come alphabetically after one with a specified ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107462/get-rows-that-come-alphabetically-after-one-with-a-specified-id/41107929#41107929) but unfortunately `Guid.CompareTo` currently (EF Core v1.1.0) is not translated to SQL and is executed locally, which will be an overkill.

Comment: Awesome!  Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SkipWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
_context.Things.SkipWhile(x=> x.Id != after).Take(limit).ToList();
```

Comment: I get a System.NotSupportedException when running this.
Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Things]).SkipWhile(x => (x.Id.ToString() != __after_0))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.SkipWhile' is currently not supported